# Creating 2D array in single malloc() call

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio-2010, pointers, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 5
#define MAX_COLS 5    

int globalvariable =  100;

void CreateMatrix(int ***Matrix)
      {
        int **ptr;
        char *cp;
        int i = 0;

        *Matrix = (int**)malloc((sizeof(int*) * MAX_ROWS) + ((MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLS)*sizeof(int)));
        ptr = *Matrix;
        cp = (char*)((char*)*Matrix + (sizeof(int*) * MAX_ROWS));

        for(i =0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++)
        {
            cp = (char*)(cp + ((sizeof(int) * MAX_COLS) * i));
            *ptr = (int*)cp;
            ptr++;      
        }

    }

    void FillMatrix(int **Matrix)
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < MAX_COLS; j++)
            {
                globalvariable++;           
                Matrix[i][j] = globalvariable;
            }
        }

    }

    void DisplayMatrix(int **Matrix)
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            for(j = 0; j < MAX_COLS; j++)
            {
                printf("%d\t", Matrix[i][j]);                        
            }
        }
    }

    void FreeMatrix(int **Matrix)
    {
       free(Matrix);
    }


    int main()
    {
      int **Matrix1, **Matrix2;

      CreateMatrix(&Matrix1);

      FillMatrix(Matrix1);

      DisplayMatrix(Matrix1);

      FreeMatrix(Matrix1);

      getchar();

      return 0;
    }
```

If the code is executed, I get the following error messages in a dialogbox.

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in sam.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in sam.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while sam.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

I tried to debug in Visual Studio, when `printf("\n");` statement of `DisplayMatrix()` is executed, same error message is reproduced.

If I press continue, it prints 101 to 125 as expected. **In Release Mode, there is no issue !!!**.

please share your ideas.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've said it before, but [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Thanks.

Comment: @unwind In VS, there is an error `cannot convert from 'void *' to 'int **'`

Comment: @Jeyaram You are supposed to compile C code as C, not as C++ (as you are currently trying to do).

Comment: @H2CO3, ya let me check.

Comment: Any reason for downvote ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *C* it is often simpler and more efficient to allocate a numerical matrix with `calloc` and use explicit index calculation ... so

```
int width = somewidth /* put some useful width computation */;
int height = someheight /* put some useful height computation */
int *mat = calloc(width*height, sizeof(int));
if (!mat) { perror ("calloc"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Then initialize and fill the matrix by computing the offset appropriately, e.g. something like

```
for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
  for (int j=0; j<height; j++)
    mat[i*height+j] = i+j;
```

if the matrix has (as you show) dimensions known at compile time, you could either stack allocate it with

```
   { int matrix [NUM_COLS][NUM_ROWS];
     /* do something with matrix */
   }
```

or heap allocate it. I find more readable to make it a `struct` like

```
   struct matrix_st { int matfield [NUM_COLS][NUM_ROWS]; };
   struct matrix_st *p = malloc(sizeof(struct matrix_st));
   if (!p) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

then fill it appropriately:

```
   for (int i=0; i<NUM_COLS; i++)
     for (int j=0; j<NUM_ROWS, j++)
        p->matfield[i][j] = i+j;
```

Remember that `malloc` returns an *uninitialized memory zone* so you need to initialize all of it.

Comment: But why do this manually, if the compiler does it for you automagically?

Answer (score 0):

A two-dimensional array is not the same as a pointer-to-pointer. Maybe you meant

```
int (*mat)[MAX_COLS] = malloc(MAX_ROWS * sizeof(*mat));
```

instead?

Comment: see FillMatrix(), I accessed it as just 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this tutorial](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm).

A very good & complete tutorial for pointers, you can go directly to Chapter 9, if you have in depth basic knowledge.